# How to extract Principal Components using FactoMineR package

Tags: r, pca

I have a dataset with a mixture of categorical and numeric features. I have used the FAMD function from the FactoMineR package to perform Principal Component Analysis. However, I am unable to figure out a way to extract them into another dataframe, so that I can perform Principal Component Regression. I have attached an image of a subset my data.

[image: Subset of Data]

```
#Performing Principal Component Analysis on Mixed Data
library(FactoMineR)
pca = FAMD(train[3:378],ncp=10)   

#Displaying the eigen value matrix
pca$eig
```

[image: Subset of eigen value matrix]

I have done the analysis so far. I need to be able to extract my principal components to a dataframe to perform Principal Component Regression. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `pca$var$coord`

Comment: Check `?FAMD` under "Value" for a list of objects that are returned in your factor-analysis object

Comment: @AdamQuek Thanks for the insights Adam. But, I need the loadings of the variables. The objects under FAMD just have matrices of contributions, square cosine coordinates, etc. I don't understand what those are.

Comment: Refer the [FAQ](http://factominer.free.fr/faq/index.html) then. The other analysis objects within `FactoMineR` are pretty similar to the `PCA` object.